# In a simple example, why the set $S$ is unbounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- There is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$ for any real number $x$. Prove or disprove this question.

Answer. Let $S=\left\{ \dfrac {1}{1+x^2}:x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. So since $S=(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is unbounded. Hence, there is no such a $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: **Why the set $S$ is unbounded?** Can you explain? Thanks...

Comment: I don't get what the proof is talking about at all. Certain $y$ definitely exists. Any $y >2$ would work. Where did the answer come from? Also $(0,1)$ is of course bounded if no more explanation provided.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That is, you say the answer is false, right?

Comment: Who said that $S$ is unbounded ?

Comment: Almost everyting is wrong. You have $S = (0,1]$. So any $y >1 $ will do.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My friend. Yes, it is false.

Comment: @xbh Yes, you are right. It said a my friend,not important. Thanks.

Comment: I have a question, if the question was ''for any real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$'', then would the below answer (fred 's answer) work this question?

Comment: @YvesDaoust May you look above my comment?

Comment: @xbh May you look above my comment?

Comment: @KathySong: what's the difference ?

Comment: @KathySong This does not make difference. Just a rearrangement of English sentences.

Comment: @KathySong I assume you were actually going to ask how about "for every real $y$ there is some real $x$ that $y > 1/(1+x^2)$". This one is false for $y < 0$.

Comment: Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1):

We have $0< \frac{1}{1+x^2} \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Hence, for each $y>1$ we have $y>\frac {1}{1+x^2}$ for  all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: if the question was ''for any real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ such that $y>\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$'', then would your answer work the question?

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb R$, then $123 >\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R:x^2\ge0\implies x^2+1\ge1\implies\frac1{x^2+1}\le 1\implies 2>\frac1{x^2+1}.$$